# Can't use .so on Mac (has bad ELF magic)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.8, buildozer, .so

I'm using buildozer to convert a python program to a phone app on Mac connected to an Android phone with the command line:

```
    buildozer android debug deploy run
```

The previous command line runs the converted app on the connected phone.But the app crashes as soon as playsound is used. As for the methods before playsound work just fine.
When I run:

```
    adb logcat | grep python
```

I get the error:

```
    ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/gi/_gi.so" has bad ELF magic
```

When I looked it up I found that Mac cannot use .so files.
Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Comment: You might have to be a bit more specific.  Is this error on your phone, in which case macOS doens't matter?  Linux uses ELF .so files, and it's saying that your .so file is invalid (it has a bad header).

Comment: I'm new to Python and buildozer so I didn't know where the error comes from. The app on my phone crashes, while connected to my computer, the mac in which I run the commands for my app to run. I thought that "_gi.so" has bad ELF magic meant that it can't work on mac. I'm still confused. If as you said it has a bad header, do you know how I can fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This error message is probably coming from your phone, not the host. I don't know how you got a corrupt .so file into your package, or where it got it from.  It looks like 'gi' is an interface library for Gnome...

Comment: @dreamers-blog were you able to fix this? Have the same issue...

Comment: @addd No unfortunately I was not able to fix it. Good luck for you, though. Please reply to this question if you ever find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I ended up fixing this when I got a similar error. (dawg.so has bad ELF magic)

Basically, the reason I got this error was because the library ("gi" in your case) was not been read properly by the android phone when deployed and hence, was "corrupted".

The bottomline reason (for me) was that it was a C/C++ library under the hood and used Cython to be converted to a Python library. Hence, this error usually means that your library needs a custom recipe.

Steps to solve it:

1. In the root directory (where .buildozer folder is found), I added a folder named dawg (the library name), and then, inside dawg, I git cloned the source files of dawg. To get the source files, you can just go to the [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/DAWG/) for that library and go to the Project links -> Homepage of their GitHub site. Once cloned, you can also remove .git, .gitignore, from the source files.
2. Once that's done, run `python3 setup.py install` in the dawg directory to install and hence, "cythonize" the source files
3. In .buildozer/android/platform/python-for android/pythonforandroid/recipes, add a new folder named "dawg" (your library name) and then, inside /dawg, make _*init*_.py where you will add your custom recipe.
4. In _*init*_.py, you can add your recipe and the path to the source files. Here is a template that worked for me, but you can customize it for you as per your requirements.

   from pythonforandroid.recipe import IncludedFilesBehaviour, CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe
   import os
   import sys

   ```
    class DAWGRecipe(IncludedFilesBehaviour, CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe):
        version = '0.8.0'
        src_filename = "../../../../../../../dawg"
        name = 'dawg'

        # Libraries it depends on
        depends = ['setuptools'] 


        call_hostpython_via_targetpython = False
        install_in_hostpython = True

        def get_recipe_env(self, arch):
            env = super().get_recipe_env(arch)
            env['LDFLAGS'] += ' -lc++_shared'
            return env


    recipe = DAWGRecipe()
   ```
5. Don't forget to alter the buildozer.spec. To its p4a.local_recipes, add the local path to `/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes` as that's where we add our recipes.
6. Clean the previous build by running `buildozer android clean`
7. Lastly, run `buildozer -v android debug deploy run` to build the app on android phone again.

Hope this helps :)